backdrop-filter: blur(); not working properly
I am using SCSS and inside my _header.scss file which I am using inside of my main.scss like this:
@use "header"; 

I have the following code (I cut out some unimportant parts like borders, margins, paddings, font-size etc.):
header {
    position: fixed;
    width: calc(96% - 32px);
    height: 34px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    z-index: 10;
    backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
    background: rgba(#000000, 0.1);

    nav {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;

            li {
                position: relative;
                z-index: 11;

                div.dropdown-content {
                    display: none;
                    position: absolute;
                    background: rgba(#000000, 0.1);
                    backdrop-filter: blur(12px);

                    &.active {
                        display: flex;
                        flex-direction: column;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Apparently the backdrop-filter: blur(12px); does not work for my div.dropdown-content, but for my header it is working just fine.
The div.dropdown-content is above my other contents on the webpage as it should. My html / PHP structure is equal to the SCSS nesting I provided.
dropdown without background blur but navbar does have background blur
I also tried adding a high z-index to div.dropdown-content, but it didn't work either. My SCSS does compile to my CSS file as it should, and other styles are working just fine, except for the blur.
Can anyone maybe help me?

Please add the relevant HTML so we can see the structure,

rgba(#000000, 0.1)?

I know what you are facing here. I also faced this condition because, not every browsers and versions support backdrop-filter.
To know about the supported version.
Supported Versions
As an Alternative to the problem is using physical filter.
filter: blur(12px);

but not barely, go to this to get idea.
Alternative to backdrop-filter

I already found a workaround. I still couldn't solve the problem as I'd wish to but putting the "dropdown-content" element outside of my header element and then applying "backdrop-filer: blur();" seems to work. Thx for your help tho :)

I had the same issue but I tried another browser and apparently, It worked.
try using: backdrop-filter: blur(12%);

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
